# Translating phrases into pig latin with string

Tags: java, string, return, translate

I am currently coding a pig latin translator that breaks down strings into words and then translate them. If any of the first four letters of a word are consonsants, it will move those letters to the back and add an "ay." If the word begins with a vowel, add "way" to the end of the word.

Apparently my pig latin translator code does not output a translated string, but instead it gives me original english words broken down in several different parts. I am a little stuck on what to go next, if anyone can help me diagnose the problem then it will be great. Thanks!

```
public class WL10Driver {
    public String convertToPig(String english){
        String pigLatin = "";
        int pigLatinWord = 0;
        String vowel = "[aeiouAEIOU]";

        for(int i = 0; i<english.length(); i++){
            char let = english.charAt(i);
            int ind = vowel.indexOf(let);

            if(ind > -1){
                if(i == 0){
                    return english+"yay";
                }
                else{
                    String start = english.substring(0,i);
                    String end = english.substring(i);
                    return end+start+"ay";
                }
            }
        }
        return english+"ay";
    }
}
```

---

It seems like the problem is with the calling method. I made it show `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,english);`.
What should I make JOptionPane show instead?

Comment: Google translate tried and failed to understand pig latin, why even bother?

Comment: Odd, the code does not look basically wrong. I will run some tests later, but how are you calling `convertToPig`, show the code around this. You aren't checking only the first 4 letters; you're checking the entire word.

Comment: it seems one error is in the "else" block of (if ind > -1) because you're putting all the characters before i at the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    return "aeiouAEIOU".contains("" + ch);
}

public String convertToPig(String english) {
    if (english == null) return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(english.length(), 4); i++) {
        char ch = english.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0 && isVowel(ch)) return english + "way";
        if (!isVowel(ch)) {
            String tmp = "";
            if (i < english.length() - 1) tmp = english.substring(i + 1);
            return english.substring(0, i) + tmp + ch + "ay";
        }
    }
    return english;
}
```